# Using 'override' for a function that has been declared using 'typedef'

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

C++ 11 introduced the 'override' specifier for functions and I find it useful as it makes it explicit that a virtual function is being overridden. However, I can't seem to get it work for a function that has been declared using a typedef.

I understand that 'override' is not a keyword, has it got something to do with that?

The following code illustrates my point:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef char ReturnsChar();

class Basic
{
    public:
    virtual char get_a();
    virtual ReturnsChar get_z;
};

char Basic::get_a() { return 'a'; }
char Basic::get_z() { return 'z'; }

class Capitalized : public Basic
{
    public:
    // Can override explicitly if I use the normal definition
    char get_a() override;

    // Compiles if I use the typedef but not 'override'
    ReturnsChar get_z;

    // Will not compile, but would like to do this
    //ReturnsChar get_z override; 

};

char Capitalized::get_a() { return 'A'; }
char Capitalized::get_z() { return 'Z'; }

int main()
{
    Basic foo;
    Capitalized bar;

    std::cout << foo.get_a() << std::endl; // a
    std::cout << foo.get_z() << std::endl; // z
    std::cout << bar.get_a() << std::endl; // A
    std::cout << bar.get_z() << std::endl; // Z
}
```

I'm using GNU's g++ 8.2.0 and the error it gives me is

> ```
> error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
> ReturnsChar get_z override;
>             ^~~~~
>                       ;
> error: ‘override’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘ctermid’?
>      ReturnsChar get_z override;
>                        ^~~~~~~~
>                        ctermid
> ```

EDIT: To address the comments, I understand this style is unclear. I am more interested about why this won't compile and what exactly 'override' does (especially because it is not a keyword). 
As an aside, I feel like typedef-ing functions might be clear in some cases, say:

```
void (*foo(int x, void (*f)(int)))(int);
```

That's hard to read, especially if comes up often. I can just typedef that as 'UpdateAddressFunction' and then mentally think of every function of that type as something that 'updates an address'.

Comment: That is a really confusing / poor use of a `typedef`. That makes it very unclear within the class that `get_z` is a method and not a variable.

Comment: ^ completely agree on that. If you add the language-lawyer tag someone might tell if this is according to the standard or not, but I dont want to see a code review that accepts this :P

Comment: Yes, in this example I agree completely. However, in my actual use case there are some very complex function prototypes and function pointers that I use, which make typedef-ing of a function useful (I like to think). Either way, the aim of my question is more about understanding why it will not compile, as opposed to style.

Comment: why not typedef the returntype only? isnt that sufficient?

Comment: Data point:  I'm using Clang, and that allows the override for Capitalized::get_z.

Comment: fwiw [you can add the `override` on the typedef and it will compile even though there is nothing overriden](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4OWQxAz0psO8IzUz). Just another hint that it is not a good idea to use typedefs in that place ;)

Comment: Compiles with clang, looks like a gcc bug.

Comment: @user463035818 Another bug. A _virt-specifier_ isn't even allowed in the syntax for a regular declaration, only in a _member-declaration_ within a class.

Comment: @aschepler yes seems like. Again clang correctly rejects it

Comment: Hint:  use `std::toupper` or `std::tolower`.  This is not the answer to your question, but will save you some coding.

Comment: My actual use case has nothing to do with capitalization of characters - it's to do with loading datasets into memory, updating shared object files, and lots of function pointer stuff. I only used capitalization to create a minimal example for explaining my question.

Comment: @CoryKramer, Actually, using `typedef` to define member function prototypes is quite an idiom. C++ being quite a fragile language, this device helps to enforce uniformity of member function prototypes across multiple declarations. In particular, prior to C++11, this device was used to overcome the lack of the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I understand that 'override' is not a keyword, has it got something to do with that?

It does: `override` is only recognised in a few specific contexts and is available as a name for ordinary use otherwise. However, I believe this is a compiler bug, and this is one context where the compiler *should* recognise it in its special meaning.

The relevant grammatical production for this is

> [class.mem]
>
> *member-declarator:
>
>   declarator virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>*

This does not require that a *virt-specifier-seq* only appear in a declaration containing parameters. The only similar requirement is stated below:

> [class.mem]p8:
>
> A *virt-specifier-seq* shall appear only in the declaration of a virtual member function (10.3).

In your case, the declaration is one of a virtual member function. I believe `override` should be accepted here.

Comment: The one catch is [lex.name]/2 "Unless otherwise specified, any ambiguity as to whether a given _identifier_ has a special meaning is resolved to interpret the token as a regular _identifier_."  I don't see a way that code could be ambiguous, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear. I'm quite pleased that I've discovered an actual compiler bug, that's one to tick off the bucket list!

Comment: @aschepler Good point. I think there are some similar cases with ambiguities. I think `struct A { struct B {}; struct B override; };` might be one, which because of what you quoted declares a non-static data member named `override`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I don't know if that's directed at me or at the OP, but FWIW, I haven't. I'd at least want to check to see whether this might already be fixed on a recent GCC 9 snapshot before reporting anything.

Comment: @hvd Directed at you. Well, I can reproduce with clang and gcc trunk. I'll go and report it then.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm surprised. The comments on the question say it works as expected on clang, and I'm not seeing a problem on that.

Comment: @hvd Good thinking, but this is not ambiguous (empty token sequence is not a legal *declarator*, only a legal *abstract-declarator*). A better example might be `struct A {}; struct B { friend A override; };`, which is not legal, but the error messages by both GCC and Clang suggest that `override` is the identifier here, e.g. (Clang++): "`error: friends can only be classes or functions`"

Comment: @ArneVogel Good point on an empty token sequence being invalid, and I always like the idea of tricking the compiler into revealing more information through its error messages.